# Почему код срабатывает только для 1 элемента?

Tags: javascript, css, native

Мой код:

```
    if(!notes) return;
    document.querySelectorAll(".note").forEach(li => li.remove());
    notes.forEach((note, id) => {
        let filterDesc = note.description.replaceAll("\n", '<br/>');
        let liTag = `<li class="note" ondblclick="deleteNote(${id})">
                        <div class="details">
                            <p>${note.title}</p>
                            <span>${filterDesc}</span>
                        </div>
                         <div class="date-wrapper">
                           <label for="date-1"> Срок годности</label>
                               <input type="date" id="date-1" />
                                  </div>
                          <button class="submit">Submit</button>
                          <div id="output">Select the dates to get started</div>
                           </div>
                        <div class="bottom-content">
                            <span>${note.date}</span>
                            <div class="settings">
                                <i onclick="showMenu(this)" class="uil uil-ellipsis-h"></i>
                                <ul class="menu">
                                    <li onclick="updateNote(${id}, '${note.title}', '${filterDesc}')"><i class="uil uil-pen"></i>Edit</li>
                                    <li onclick="deleteNote(${id})"><i class="uil uil-trash"></i>Delete</li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </li>`;
        addBox.insertAdjacentHTML("beforebegin", liTag);
        let submits = document.querySelectorAll(".submit");
        submits.forEach((submit) => {
            submit.addEventListener('click', handleClick);
        })
    });
}
showNotes();


function handleClick() {
    let date1 = new Date(document.getElementById("date-1").value);
    let output = document.getElementById("output");
    let currentDate = new Date();
    if (date1.getTime()) {
        let timeDifference = date1.getTime() - currentDate;
        let dayDifference = Math.round(timeDifference/ (1000 * 3600 * 24));
        if (dayDifference > 0) {
            output.innerHTML = `Срок годности составляет ${dayDifference} дней`;
        } else {
            output.innerHTML = `Срок годности истёк`;
        }
    } else {
        output.innerHTML = "Please select a valid date";
    }

}
```

Срок годности (функция handleClick) срабатывает только для 1 элемента. Как можно поправить?

Comment: Навешивание слушателя на кнопки надо бы вынести за пределы первого foreach как минимум. А то вы в каждой итерации это делаете

Comment: let submits = document.getElementsByClassName("submit")[0];
     submits.addEventListener('click', handleClick);         вы это имеете в виду?

Comment: Да, вы перебираете notes, добавляете их по очереди. А уже потом вне этого цикла вешаете слушатели.